# Extracting Fields Value using Lucene

Tags: lucene, information-retrieval, information-extraction

My problem is that I would like to parse one document only (not multiple documents) with textual data and extract some relevant information based on my query.

For example:
If I have the following text:

```
This is a sample document.
Name: Te
Age: 25
Email: te@gmail.com
Some text in the end of the document
```

I would like to extract the fields (Name, Age, Email) with there corresponding values

Many of the examples I found are mainly to search for documents that matches a query. I would appreciate if someone can guide me on which Analyzer or Query classes to lookin in lucene library or any materials to read.

Comment: I'm not aware of functionality in Lucene for generalised extraction of field/value pairs. Why do you want to use Lucene?

Comment: Well, what I had in mind is to use lucene to index a file and query, for example the keyword "Name", in order to get the term's position in the text. Afterwards I would get the following n consecutive tokens from that position as a value for "Name" until I hit another keyword "Age", and so on. Please correct me if I am complicating things. If you can advise me to use another library other than Lucene please do let me know. Thanks

Comment: If you only need to extract Name, Age and Email and their respective values, I'd use a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started. With a regular expression, in Java, where the document content has been assigned to the variable `text`:

```java
String expr = "Name\:\s(\w+)\sAge\:\s+(\d+)\s+Email\:\s+([a-z0-9.@]+)\s+";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(expr, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = r.matcher(text);
if (m.find( ))
{
    System.out.println("Name: " + m.group(1) );
    System.out.println("Age: " + m.group(2) );
    System.out.println("Email: " + m.group(3) );
}
else { System.out.println("Match not found"); }
```